# Nth-Child Counting Span Elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem where `nth-child(3n+1)` keeps counting my spans. Here's what I mean:

```css
#main .item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: red;
}
span.clear {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

#main > div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="one" class="item"></div>
    <div id="two" class="item"></div>
    <div id="three" class="item"></div>
    <span class="clear"></span>
    <div id="four" class="item"></div>
    <div id="five" class="item"></div>
    <div id="six" class="item"></div>
    <span class="clear"></span>
    <div id="seven" class="item"></div>
    <div id="eight" class="item"></div>
    <div id="nine" class="item"></div>
</div>
```

It should color the following squares:

- 3 * 0 + 1 = 1
- 3 * 1 + 1 = 4
- 3 * 2 + 1 = 7

But for some reason, in all my browsers and test I keep getting the following returned:

- Square 1 gets colored
- Square 6 gets colored
- Square 8 gets colored

I have no idea why it's happening other than it's counting span or maybe I'm misinterpreting `nth-child` can somebody explain in detail what's going wrong and why I don't get my expected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `:nth-of-type`, not `:nth-child`

```css
#main .item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background-color: red;
}
span.clear {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#main > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="one" class="item">1</div>
    <div id="two" class="item">2</div>
    <div id="three" class="item">3</div> 
    <span class="clear"></span>
    <div id="four" class="item">4</div>
    <div id="five" class="item">5</div>
    <div id="six" class="item">6</div> 
    <span class="clear"></span>
    <div id="seven" class="item">7</div>
    <div id="eight" class="item">8</div>
    <div id="nine" class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Your `:nth-child(3n+1)` formula will select the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, children of #main *if they are divs*. So what happens is that the first child of #main is a div. Great, it gets selected properly and colored blue. Next the fourth child is selected. Sadly it's a span, not a div, so it's ignored. The seventh child is a div (with the id of six), and since it's a div it gets selected, although not the way you hoped. Think of this in a right to left sort of way. `div:nth-of-type(3n+1)` will run through the children of #main, selecting the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th.. elements, *and then* apply the selected properties if that element is a div.

Comment: `:nth-of-type` makes sense, but why doesn't `div:` specifically say "Look for `div` children"? When using `nth-child` should the pseudo-selector be on it's own? `#main :nth-child(3n+1)` ?

Comment: Because `:nth-child` looks at siblings. As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) explains, "The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element.

This can more clearly be described this way: the matching element is the bth child of an element after all its children have been split into groups of a elements each."

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: It doesn't have to be on its own, but the key here is that it will always work independently of any other selector that you attach to it. The only purpose in qualifying it with another selector is so you don't match the wrong elements elsewhere. For example, it's perfectly fine to say `div:nth-child(...)` if you want to make sure you only select divs this way, not other elements, or `.foo:nth-child(...)` if you want to make sure you only select `.foo` elements.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Or you can qualify it with a contextual selector, as you have done with `#main >`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee - I'm going to add a short explanation in my answer that will hopefully clear it up a little.

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock and j08691 that makes sense. I suppose it works the same with `:first/last-child` selectors too which I didin't realize :$

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Indeed, but then again, most people misunderstand first and last in much the same way as they do nth.

Comment: It's an easy one to get confused on.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child`.

```css
#main > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) { background-color: blue; }
```

*P.S.: 3 * 2 + 1 = **7***

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqf7xu4d/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `span` elements count as children. You should be using `nth-of-type`.

```
#main > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/23hbgxm1/)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers you should use `:nth-of-type` instead, but you may still use `:nth-child` if you remove all the empty `span` from the markup (empty markup only for styling purpose is never a good idea, especially in terms of code mantainability) and if you modify the style like so

```
#main > div:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: blue;
    clear: left;
}
```